# UiView.animateWithDuration Not Animating Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewanimationtransition, ios-animations

I am trying to animate show/hide of search bar using below code (The search bar should come from left and expand to right within 1-2 seconds). However, it doesn't animate and searchBar is immediately shown no matter how much time I put. I noticed following:

- Duration is not respected
- Not even delay is respected
- Animation is not happening. Component is immediately shown

  ```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  //code to get selected value...
  //Hide the collection view and show search bar

  UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0,
      delay: 0.0,
      options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve,
      animations: {
          self.searchBar.hidden = false
          self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44) //This doesn't work either
      },
      completion: { (finished: Bool) in
          return true
      })
  }
  ```

I am using Xcode 7, iOS 8 and Swift 2.0. I have seen at other solution, but none of them works for me. Kindly help...

**Update**: It worked with below code. However, it used default animation option of `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut` and `TransitionNone`

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7,
                animations: {
                    self.searchBar.alpha = 1.0
                    self.searchBarRect.origin.x = self.searchBarRect.origin.x + 200
                    self.searchBar.frame = self.searchBarRect
                },
                completion: { (finished: Bool) in
                    return true
            })
```

Comment: Where are you setting the search bar alpha to 0?

Comment: I suspect frame change will work in autolayout system.

Comment: Alpha is set to zero just before the uiview code

Comment: That's what I pointed, if you are using autolayout then frame change of a view won't work..

Comment: Damn! My mistake. To hide, I was setting `hidden` to true and later, to show it up, I was using `alpha`. When I used alpha on both sides, animation started working.

However, whatever Animation option I use, it always shows one animation as if it is 'popping out from center'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the animateWithDuration, set the XPosition to -200 and YPosition to -200.

Like Daniel Suggested, you need to also change the alpha from something other than 1.0 in order to see it "fade in".

Are you using autolayout?  If you are, you may want to animate the constraints instead of the frame.

Finally, are you sure you've wired up the search bar properly?

Edit: PS, I would keep the duration to something like 3.0 or 5.0.   10.0 will take forever and may make you think that it isn't doing anything because of how long it takes.  Make it 3.0 or 5.0 (max) just for testing and then decrease to where you want it.

Comment: Lotta different ways to handle that.  One way is to start 2 different animations (1 to do the moving, the other to do the fade).  set one animation to be offset start by like 1 sec after the 1st one starts.  The other is to use the animation GROUP - where you can get a little more fine-grain control

Comment: I would appreciate if I could see a working code snippet

Comment: I am choosing your solution as the answer with few exceptions:

`10 seconds is not like forever`, `I am on AutoLayout, but I don't need to animate constraints, I would still animate frame`